# Which is the best website to choose the best Background and Foreground colors?

Tags: color, color-theory

I am building a Flat color based website and am having trouble choosing the color scheme. I need a background color (section background) and a foreground color (element background). The element, in this case a button is on top of the section background.

I have come across multiple color palette websites like [Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/explore/newest/) and [Coolors](http://coolors.co/). They are great. But, all of them give me multiple colors making it hard for me to decide. Is there a website that gives me just a Foreground and Background color? Or, is there a way to test how well two colors would do as a background and foreground color? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check [this](http://paletton.com/#uid=1000u0kllllaFw0g0qFqFg0w0aF) and set color schema in monochromatic (which mean its only one color to choose).

Answer (score -1):

You should go through [this website](http://www.colourlovers.com/web/palettes) for your website colors.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/answering